# Uncaught TypeError Failed to set the 'voice' property on 'SpeechSynthesisUtterance': Failed to convert value to 'SpeechSynthesisVoice'

Tags: javascript

How can I change `voice` value of `speechSynthesisUtterance` object to other value like number or string without getting this error?

```
SpeechSynthesisUtterance Object:
 SpeechSynthesisUtterance {text: 'hi', lang: '', voice: null, volume: 1, rate: 1, …}
    

 html.html:49  Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'voice' property on 'SpeechSynthesisUtterance': Failed to convert value to 'SpeechSynthesisVoice'.
    at HTMLSelectElement.changeSpeaker
```

When I changed value of `speechSynthesisUtterance.voice` it returned me error.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look right so I pulled this function out of an old project to demonstrate text to speech and available options...

```
function TextToSpeech(Txt){

var Voices=speechSynthesis.getVoices();

if(Voices.length>-1){

 var Msg=new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();


 /* Available options...

 Msg.voice=Voices[0]; // change the voice

 Msg.lang='en-US'; // change the language

 Msg.rate=0.7;  // change the speed

 */


 Msg.text=Txt;

 Msg.onend=function(event){speechSynthesis.cancel();};

 speechSynthesis.speak(Msg);


} else {

  alert('You don\'t seem to have a default narrator voice set up.');

 }

}
```

Usage: TextToSpeech('hello');

NB: You can always pass any options as function parameters if it suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I changed msg.voice with voices[i].voiceURI value. and I was wrong you should give it array element like array[0] thanks!